# Inheritance of modules in OCaml

Tags: inheritance, module, ocaml

I have already defined an interface and a module:

```
module type BASE =
  sig
    type 'a base
    val ...
    ...
  end

module base =
  (struct
    type 'a base
    let ...
    ...
  end: BASE)
```

I would like to define another interface `DERIVED` inherited from `BASE`, which includes all the types and signatures of `BASE`, and has its own types and declarations. Then I could define another module `Derived` whose type is `DERIVED`.

Could anyone tell me how to do it? Is it necessarily the object feature of OCaml?

Going further, is it possible to change the names of the types of `DERIVED`: for instance, it is called `'a derived` instead of '`a base`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `include` on both signature and implementations.

```
module type DERIVED = sig 
  include BASE
  val foo : ...
end

module Derived : DERIVED = struct
  include Base
  let foo = ...
end
```

This is a simple inclusion of structure. It is not "(implementation) inheritance" in the sense of OOP, because there is no late-binding (open recursion) involved. If you define a value `f` in `Derived` that was previously defined in `Base`, it will shadow the previous `f`, but call to `f` from `Base` will still use the old value, not the new implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... what about my second question: "is it possible to change the names of the types of `DERIVED`: for instance, it is called `'a derived` instead of `'a base`"?